# watermarking gallery items

Tags: functions, gallery

How can I add an image watermark to only those images which are to be published in gallery using a function in `functions.php`? Images can be in `.jpg`, `.png`, `.gif` format.

I also [found this snippet](http://dolcepixel.com/how-to-watermark-all-your-uploaded-images/) which serves the same but it watermarks all the uploaded images.

Comment: Have you tried to alter that code? If so, post what you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I put into a `watermark.php` file :

```
<?php
// loads a png, jpeg or gif image from the given file name
function imagecreatefromfile($image_path) {
// retrieve the type of the provided image file
list($width, $height, $image_type) = getimagesize($image_path);

// select the appropriate imagecreatefrom* function based on the determined
// image type
switch ($image_type)
 {
  case IMAGETYPE_GIF: return imagecreatefromgif($image_path); break;
  case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: return imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path); break;
  case IMAGETYPE_PNG: return imagecreatefrompng($image_path); break;
  default: return ''; break;
 }
}

// load source image to memory
$image = imagecreatefromfile($_GET['image']);
if (!$image) die('Unable to open image');

// load watermark to memory
$watermark = imagecreatefromfile($_GET['watermark']);
if (!$image) die('Unable to open watermark');

// calculate the position of the watermark in the output image (the
// watermark shall be placed in the lower right corner)
 $watermark_pos_x = imagesx($image) - imagesx($watermark) - 8;
$watermark_pos_y = imagesy($image) - imagesy($watermark) - 10;

// merge the source image and the watermark
  imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0,
  imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));

// output watermarked image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image, '', 100);  // use best image quality (100)

// remove the images from memory
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

?>

then into a `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (800x...|...x800)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)
RewriteRule ^([^tn].*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ /wp-content/uploads/watermark.php?image=$1&watermark=watermark.png [NC]
```

Place the `watermark.php` + `.htaccess` + `watermark.png` into `wp-content/uploads` folder (or any other place if you adapt the `.htaccess` line).

Here the .htaccess grabs any request for jpg, png ou gif that contains 800x or x800 in the name (to apply watermark on big images only), redirect it to the `watermark.php` script who add the watermark on the image.

This is a starter that you should adapt to your needs by defining the rules to apply in the `.htaccess`file. For our case, we had define 800x800 size in the media options.